# efficient method for enabling/disabling a button which depends on more than two fields

Tags: c#, winforms

I was making a winforms application, my objective is to set enabled properties of a button in order to enable or disable the button, which is depending upon more than one controls (3 in my case). It can be done by two methods(if other,let me know!)
1. Should I create a different thread for this purpose which will check the properties of all controls in a loop
2. or I should check the required condition every time an event occurs on all 3 controls?

Which is more efficient/convenient to achieve the task?

Comment: Why waste a thread if the three controls tell you (by raising an event) when their properties changed?

Comment: definitely not another thread. What will it do, loop? If not, whats it waiting for? You just have to hack the event handling code out

Comment: Create a single event handler method.  Wire up all your desired control events from all the controls that will participate to that event handler method.  Within the event handler, determine based on the current state of your controls whether the button should be disabled/enabled.

Comment: You can create a property on the form that returns true/false based on the state of the other controls and then use data binding to bind the Enabled property of the button to the property just created. Or you can do what you suggest and test the logic in the event handlers manually each time the controls change.

Comment: It is not whether it depends on a control that matters, but how you access it. You may or may not need to raise events depending on your situation. The important thing to do is to think about how these properties are accessed and changed in memory. If you are not sure what to do, pick @Rene advice.

Comment: @rory.ap best one! thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use a loop for this unless other activity needs to occur at the same time (such as in a fast-paced game).  Even then, it's unlikely to be necessary.  It's better to let the EventHandler do its thing and share the handler between your controls.  This will be particularly simple if you use `CheckBoxes`, as you are essentially testing three binary conditions. The method will be even simpler, no matter how you approach it:

```
private void ToggleCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{              
      List<CheckBox> Cons = new List<CheckBox>(){CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3};       
      int score = 0;
      foreach(CheckBox cb in Cons)
                score += cb.Checked == true ? 1 : 0;  
      myButton.Enabled = (score >= 2); 
}
```

Comment: Your example is awful. You allocate a list, made a cycle and do a lot of condition checks every time when event raised on any connected control. None of this is necessary for your particular case. And while it, probably, won't affect application performance, such coding style will strengthen very bad coding habits.